# Array last element automatically gets garbage

Tags: c++

[I got this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP1R5.jpg)

Learning how to use arrays and I got an exercise to check if the array is in an ascending order, after the first run, this is what I got and I cant find the problem.

when I'm printing the array it shows in the last array some garbage.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int CAPACITY1 = 5;

int main()
{

int arr1[CAPACITY1];
bool a = false;

//init the first input
cout << "Enter 6 numbers: " << endl;
cin >> arr1[0];
int max = arr1[0];
int NoE = 1;

//init the loop to insert numbers
for (int i = 1; i <= CAPACITY1; i++) {
    cout << "Enter 6 numbers: " << endl;
    cin >> arr1[i];
    NoE++;

    //check if input is bigger than max
    if (arr1[i] > max) 
        max = arr1[i];
    else
        a = true;
}

if (a == true)
    cout << "The array is not in an ascending order" << endl;
else
    cout << "The array is in an ascending order" << endl;

cout << NoE;

//end
cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that my array is jumping out of bounds, my question is why..

Comment: Because you coded it that way.

Comment: Ok, but then I get an array with only 5 numbers and not 6

Comment: http://prntscr.com/aipmxz

Comment: Yes, `CAPACITY1` is 5, so the array has 5 elements.

Comment: Its counting from 0 so it should be 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: No, the array has 5 elements. Not 6, not 7. Sorry, you need `for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY1; i++) `

Comment: @ArielMoose Since you have defined your array as `int arr1[CAPACITY1];`, it has 5 elements, from 0 to 4. Trying to access the element at position 5 is wrong. That said, in your messages you talk about 6 numbers. If you want to store 6 elements, change the value of `CAPACITY1` to 6 (`const int CAPACITY1 = 6;`). By the way, this shows why it would be a good idea to avoid hard-coded numbers (6, in this case) and always use variables. Try with `cout << "Enter " << CAPACITY1 << " numbers: " << endl;`. This way, the size of the array and the messages will always match.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes in arrays in C++ are zero based. That means, that array with capacity of `N`, declared as `T arr[N]`, have indexes starting at `0` and ending with `N - 1`.

For accessing such array using `for` loop, use this

```
for (int index = 0; index < N; ++index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop here operates from 1 to 5:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= CAPACITY1; i++) {
    cout << "Enter 6 numbers: " << endl;
    cin >> arr1[i];
```

So you only enter five numbers and you never put anything in `arr1[0]` and you do put something in `arr[5]` which is invalid.

Aside from that, I suspect you *may* have missed the point of the exercise. If this is a homework assignment then I imagine they want you to iterate over an existing array and report if it is in ascending order.

Comment: Starting from 1 may be correct if the goal is to determine if the array is in ascending order: `bool is_ascending = true; for (int i = 1; i < CAPACITY1; i++) { if ( arr1[i] < arr1[i-1] ) { is_ascendig = false; break; }}`

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is wrong, and is going out of bounds.Note that arrays in C++ start at 0, not 1. The correct for loop is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY1; i++) {
    cout << "Enter 6 numbers: " << endl;
    cin >> arr1[i];
    NoE++;

    //check if input is bigger than max
    if (arr1[i] > max) 
        max = arr1[i];
    else
        a = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These 2 lines:

```
int CAPACITY1 = 5;
int arr1[CAPACITY1];
```

mean that the size of your array `arr1` is 5, that is, it has 5 elements, from 0 to 4. Trying to access the element at position 5 is wrong.

That said, in your `cout` messages you talk about 6 numbers. If you want to store 6 elements, change the value of `CAPACITY1` to 6, like:

```
const int CAPACITY1 = 6;
```

By your comments I think you are getting confused with the size of the array, possibly because you have heard something like "The index of the last element is always off by 1". Yes it is, but it doesn't mean that to store 6 elements you should use the number 5 when you define it! If you want 6 elements, the size must be 6, there is no trap here. The tricky part is that the index will start from 0, and therefore the last element is at position `[size - 1]`, not at `[size]`. To clarify:

**If you declare `int arr1[5];` you will have 5 elements, with the index ranging from 0 to 4.**
**If you declare `int arr1[6];` you will have 6 elements, with the index ranging from 0 to 5.**

By the way, this shows why it would be a good idea to avoid hard-coded numbers (6, in this case) and always use variables. Try with

```
cout << "Enter " << CAPACITY1 << " numbers: " << endl;
```

This way, the size of the array and the messages will always match.

To summarize, if you want to work with 6 numbers, you need to use

```
const int CAPACITY1 = 6;
```

and, since you deal with the first element (at index 0) before the loop, the loop must start at 1 and run until the last element, which has index 5, so:

```
for (int i = 1; i < CAPACITY1; i++) {
```

On a side note, your logic to check whether the array is in ascending order is confusing. For you, `a == true` means it is *not* ascending. It works, but it is counter-intuitive. I would suggest to change it.